# http2 apache2 module disabled but still see h2 requests

Tags: apache-http-server, http-2

I have installed http2 module to try it. now I want to disable it.
I installed it with :

```
a2enmod http2
```

and I added this line to my vhost :

```
Protocols h1 http/1.1
```

to disable it I removed the line in the vhost file and used :

```
a2dismod http2
```

when i look to /mods-enabled/ I don't see it any more.
I restarted apache2

but, when I do requests to my site, i still see http2 requests: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l5YK.jpg

any idea of why this happens ?

Comment: Where does it show that those requests are being made to your server?

Comment: hi @grawity actually, those requests are not made to my server. even when i enable http2, this is not the case, so my problem is : http2 enabled but no h2 request made to my server. an Idea ?